AWS ECS Update-Service Fails with "ServiceNotFoundException" Despite Service Being Active
Question:
I am trying to automate the deployment of a service in AWS ECS using a GitHub Actions pipeline. The pipeline works as expected for creating a new service, but when attempting to update an existing service, it fails with the following error:
An error occurred (ServiceNotFoundException) when calling the UpdateService operation:
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.

Here is the relevant section of my pipeline script:
- name: Ensure ECS service exists and deploy
  run: |
    CLUSTER_NAME=${{ inputs.cluster_name }}
    TASK_NAME=$(jq -r '.family' updated-task-definition.json)
    SERVICE_FILE="updated-service.json"
    SERVICE_NAME=$(basename ${{ inputs.task_definition_file }} .json | sed 's/task-/service-/')
    TASK_DEFINITION_ARN=$(aws ecs list-task-definitions --sort DESC --query "taskDefinitionArns" \
    --output json | jq -r --arg TASK_NAME "$TASK_NAME" '[.[] | select(contains($TASK_NAME))][0]')
    echo $TASK_DEFINITION_ARN

    SERVICE_EXISTS=$(aws ecs describe-services \
      --cluster "$CLUSTER_NAME" \
      --services "$SERVICE_NAME" \
      --query "services[0].serviceName" \
      --output text --no-cli-pager || echo "")

    if [[ -z "$SERVICE_EXISTS" ]]; then
      echo "Service $SERVICE_NAME not found. Creating service..."
      aws ecs create-service \
        --cluster "$CLUSTER_NAME" \
        --service-name "$SERVICE_NAME" \
        --task-definition "$TASK_DEFINITION_ARN" \
        --cli-input-json file://"create-service.json" \
        --no-cli-pager
    else
      echo "Service $SERVICE_NAME exists. Updating service..."
      jq '.' updated-service.json
      
      aws ecs update-service \
        --cluster "$CLUSTER_NAME" \
        --service "$SERVICE_NAME" \
        --task-definition "$TASK_DEFINITION_ARN" \
        --cli-input-json file://updated-service.json \
        --no-cli-pager
    fi

Observations:

The service task_gms-pre is active and listed in the AWS ECS console.
The SERVICE_EXISTS check correctly detects that the service exists.
Despite the service being active, the update-service command fails with ServiceNotFoundException.

Here is an example of the output JSON being used for the service update:
{
  "service": "service_app-pre",
  "cluster": "cluster_app_pre",
  "loadBalancers": [
    {
      "targetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:targetgroup/ecs-service-apppre/xxxxxxxxxx",
      "containerName": "apppre",
      "containerPort": 8080
    }
  ],
  "serviceRegistries": [],
  "desiredCount": 2,
  "deploymentConfiguration": {
    "deploymentCircuitBreaker": {
      "enable": true,
      "rollback": true
    },
    "maximumPercent": 200,
    "minimumHealthyPercent": 0
  }
}

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Debugging Steps Taken:

Verified that the CLUSTER_NAME and SERVICE_NAME variables are correct and match the ECS console values. It works on a terminal with aws cli
Used --no-cli-pager to avoid interactive prompts.
Confirmed that the task definition ARN is valid and active.

Questions:

What could be causing the ServiceNotFoundException in this scenario?
Are there specific restrictions or nuances with the update-service command that I might be overlooking?
Is there a better way to debug or log ECS API calls to pinpoint the root cause?


You are providing service and cluster in both CLI options and updated-service.json. Are these matching?. Can you try removing them from json file?
